# How to show NSPopover without dismissing the first responder?

Tags: swift, macos, accessibility, nsevent

I'm working on a mac app that has similar functionalities to the [rocket app](https://matthewpalmer.net/rocket/).

Whenever the user types `:` outside of my app I'll show an `NSPopover` with `NSTableView` near the cursor.
The problem I'm facing here is that The moment I show the `NSPopover` it becomes the first responder and the user couldn't continue typing.

So I tried this, Showed the NSPopover without making a first responder, and used `Global listener` to listen UpArrow, DownArrow and Enter actions to navigate and select results.
The downside of this approach: Let's say I'm composing a new mail, and the cursor responding to the up/down arrow events, eventually moved to other lines.

```
func showWidget(at origin: CGPoint, height: CGFloat) {
    let popUpView = NSView()
    let window: NSWindow = .getWindow(with: .init(width: 1, height: 1), origin: origin, withBorder: false)
    window.contentView?.setBackground(color: .white)
    window.contentView?.addSubview(popUpView)
    popUpView.alignEdges()
    popUpView.setBackground(color: .white)
    window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)

    popover.contentViewController = widgetController
    popover.behavior = .semitransient
    popover.contentSize = .init(width: .inputWidgetSize.width, height: 200)
    popover.animates = false
    popover.appearance = NSAppearance.init(named: .darkAqua)
    popover.show(relativeTo: .init(origin: .init(x: .zero, y: 0), size: .init(width: .inputWidgetSize.width, height: height)), of: popUpView, preferredEdge: .maxY)
  }
```

Attaching video for reference:
**The functionality that I'm expecting**

[image]

**From my app**

[image]

**Note:** Notice the cursor position to understand what going wrong.

Comment: Which view should be focused, the table view or the text view? What is `Global listener`?

Comment: No @Willeke, I don't think that helps. I meant this as Global Listener ```NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEvents(matching: .keyDown, handler: )```

I'm looking to find a way to handle upArrow, DownArrow and Enter events by not disturbing the user typing from the other app.

Comment: Users should be able to continue typing from another app, whenever they press downArrow, UpArrow and Enter I need to handle those and replace the content if needed. Like the rocket app.

Comment: Sorry, I missed "outside of my app". It looks like Rocket is using an event tap.

Comment: Sorry, couldn't get this, You assuming that the rocket app is using tap event to fill the results?

Comment: See [Quartz Event Services](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/quartz_event_services) and https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmacos%5D+event+tap